# why angular material not support in windows(safari) and IE9 (IE10->partial support)?

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser, angular-material

why angular material layout not support in windows safari and IE9 and it support IE10 partially. the general buttons and animations will support, but not the layouts in angular material.
the angular material website itself is not working in IE9, the layout will be not aligned properly as other browsers.  is there any way to fix it.
[image]

Comment: You have to ask the developers why they chose to use features that are not present in older browsers.

Comment: Is  there a hack or something to fix it?

Comment: Angular Material Design uses flexbox for layout, so other than changing the source: no.